# The equation that fits the points, with only positive terms

Tags: quadratics, approximation, curves, data-analysis

While looking for the equation to fits the following points:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.2 |
| 50 | 1 |
| 100 | 5 |

I found (following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLar40Dd_Us&t=263s):

```
0.064 * x**2 - 0.16 * x + 0.2
```

Seems to do it.

[image]

But then I noticed I actually want the equation with all positive terms, so it will be increasing all the way.

How do I find the equation that fits the points, with only positive terms?

Answer (score 1):

If you know you want to have a quadratic, call it $ax^2 + bx + c$. Then, the 3 points give you 3 simultaneous equations:

$$0.2 = c$$
$$1 = 50^2 a + 50b + c$$
$$5 = 100^2 a + 100b + c$$

Clearly, the first equation reduces this to just 2 simultaneous equations:

$$2500a + 50b + 0.2= 1$$
$$10000a + 100b + 0.2 = 5$$

which has the unique solution you gave in your question. If you want it to be a quadratic, this is the unique quadratic going through those 3 points.

You could find a polynomial of higher degree, for example a cubic, of which there are a whole family passing through your points.

Comment: I definitely don’t require it to be quadratic. Need to be increasing all the way though. Seems I should look for a cubic then

Comment: Does it need to be polynomial? If not, try something like $a  e^{kx}$

Comment: Don't need to be polynomial.